# Compact subset of a t.d.l.c. group contained in compact-open subgroup?

Tags: topological-groups, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be a totally disconnected, locally compact group which is the union of its compact-open subgroups (or perhaps only $\sigma$-compact), and let $C \subset G$ be a compact set. Can one conclude that $C$ is contained in some compact-open subgroup of $G$?

Comment: However, a theorem of Platonov ensures that if every *finite* subset is contained in a compact open subgroup, then every compact subset is contained in a compact open subgroup. [Here "open" is not important since in every locally compact group, every compact subgroup is contained in a compact open subgroup.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The famous Burnside problem asks whether a  finitely generated group, whose  elements all have finite order,  must be
a finite group.

This question was answered in the negative in 1964 by Golod and Shafarevich.

If $G$ is a counter-example to the Burnside problem, once it is equipped with the discrete topology, it is also a counter-example to the question posed by the OP.
The finite generating set is a compact set not contained in any compact group!